# node.js redis async query

Tags: node.js, redis

Hope someone can assist with a (simple) async question on node-redis. I'm trying to load a set from a hash in the redis db and then use that populated set further on. Here's the code snippet :-

```
var redis_client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_URL); 

redis_client.hgetall(target_hash,function(e,o){

    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(target){

        // get the "name" from the hash         
        redis_client.hget(o[target],"name",function(e,o){
        if (e){
                 console.log("Error occurred getting key: " + e);
              }
        else {
                 redis_client.sadd("newset",o);
             }
    });

});

// the following line prints nothing - why ?? 

redis_client.smembers("newset",redis.print);
```

When I examine the contents of "newset" in redis it is populated as expected, but at runtime it displayed as empty. I'm sure it's an async issue - any help much appreciated !

Comment: A humourous analogy that will serve you well when dealing with async issues - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/-soVdfMGug8/vRmqIcAZ5zsJ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hgetall` is an asynchronous call: when it receives a reply from the redis server, it will eventually call your callback `function (target) { ... }`. But within your script, it actually returns immediately. Since `hgetall` returns very fast, Node will immediately run the next statement, `smembers`. But at this point the `sadd` statements haven’t run yet (even if your system is very fast because there hasn’t been a context switch yet).

What you need to do is to make sure `smembers` isn’t called before all the possible `sadd` calls have executed. redis_client provides the `multi` function to allow you to queue up all the `sadd` calls and run a callback when they’re all done. I haven’t tested this code, but you could try this:

```
var redis_client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_URL);

redis_client.hgetall(target_hash, function(e, o) {
  var multi = redis_client.multi();
  var keys = Object.keys(o);
  var i = 0;

  keys.forEach(function (target) {
    // get the "name" from the hash     
    redis_client.hget(o[target], "name", function(e, o) {
      i++;
      if (e) {
        console.log("Error occurred getting key: " + e);
      } else {
        multi.sadd("newset", o);
      }

      if (i == keys.length) {
        multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
          console.log("MULTI got " + replies.length + "replies");
          redis_client.smembers("newset", redis.print);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Some libraries have a built-in equivalent of `forEach` that allows you to specify a function to be called when the loop is all done. If not, you have to manually keep track of how many callbacks there have been and call `smembers` after the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use multi unless you need actually need a transaction.

just keep a counter of the transactions and call smembers in the final callback

```
var redis_client = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_URL); 
var keys = Object.keys(o);
var i = 0;
redis_client.hgetall(target_hash,function(e,o){

    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(target){

        // get the "name" from the hash         
        redis_client.hget(o[target],"name",function(e,o){
        i++
        if (e){
                 console.log("Error occurred getting key: " + e);
              }
        else {
                 redis_client.sadd("newset",o);
                 if (i == keys.length) {
                    redis_client.smembers("newset", redis.print);
                 }

         }});
```